# Changing elements of a large matrix according to a submatrix rule

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop

I have a 105x105 matrix B (which is in fact a 35x35 group of <3x3> matrices concatenated) and I have to change its elements according to a rule which works on the <3x3> matrices.

Given that any submatrix can have only on "1" per row and the "1" can only occur at (1,1) and/or (2,2) and/or (3,3).

Hence the only submatrices possible are

[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0], which turns into [0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0]

[1 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0], which turns into [1 1 1;0 0 0;0 0 0]

[0 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 0], which turns into [0 0 0;1 1 1;0 0 0]

[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 1], which turns into [0 0 0;0 0 0;1 1 1]

[1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 0], which turns into [1 1 1;1 1 1;0 0 0]

[1 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 1], which turns into [1 1 1;0 0 0;1 1 1]

[0 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1], which turns into [0 0 0;1 1 1;1 1 1]

and [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1], which turns into [1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1]

I'm using `[1 1 1]*any(submatrix,2)` to change the values acc. to the rule and it works fine. But I'm using the following loop to go through all the submatrices:

```
    for i=1:3:103
     for j=1:3:103
      temp=A(i:i+2,j:j+2);
      temp=[1 1 1]*any(temp,2);
      A(i:i+2,j:j+2)=temp
     end
    end
```

Isn't there an alternative loopless method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to reshape the array so that the reassignment becomes easy:

```
%# remember size of A
[nRows,nCols] = size(A);

%# reshape A to 3xn
%# transpose so that we get each "row" as a separate column
temp = reshape(A',3,[]);

%# overwrite temp with the rows filled in 
temp = repmat(any(temp,1),3,1);

%# reshape to recreate the original array
%# and transpose
B = reshape(temp,nRows,nCols)';
```

Comment: It works perfectly. How did you come up with such a solution?

Comment: @KunalRmth: I was simply thinking about what the operation was (fill a row with ones if it contains a one), and then wondered how we could arrange the original array to facilitate the operation. Also, I'm really good with Matlab ;)

Comment: since you are so good with Matlab, see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923458/apply-iterative-functions-on-large-array> which really needs some loop-removings.